# Is it possible to use wildcards for Notepad++ search & replace

Tags: notepad++, wildcard, replace

I so hope you can do this, I have over a 1000 occurrences of a of an instance that slightly changes through out the document that needs to be changed slightly and I was wondering if I can do this in notepad++

what I need to change is:

```
[[image:CWI155 ICS Work station setup_html_2b817479.gif||height="4" width="602"]]
```

to

```
{{lightbox image="CWI155 ICS Work station setup_html_2b817479.gif" height="4" width="602" group="a"/}}
```

Any help would be most grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the search mode to "Regular expression" and using the following search/replace values.

Find what:

```
\[\[image:([^\|]+)\|\|height="(\d+)" width="(\d+)"\]\]
```

Replace with:

```
{{lightbox image="\1" height="\2" width="\3" group="a"/}}
```

If the image, height and width values are the changing parts this should do the trick.

Comment: I haven't checked your regex, but I agree that regex's are the right approach.